# make animation to loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

i have a text animation ("try again" in the fiddle example) that jumps up the problem is that it's working only when the pages load and i need it to loop.

here is the fiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/uqcLn/49/

```
var directions = ["-=10px", "+=10px"];
    function move(i){
        $(".white span").animate({ "left": directions[i] }, 300, function(){
             move((i ===0)? 1 : 0);
        });
    }

    move(0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay... After playing with this for like an hour this is as close as I can get it... The problem is your move function is getting itself stuck in a huge loop and then youre never cancelling it. Take a look at what I did. In the call back of the first animate you move it again but reset the style or else it ends up moving so far to the left before it can go back to the right.

Then I made it so once you mouse over the wall again it resets everything and once you mouse over the way again it starts the try again function. (personally I think you renamed the classes wrong but whatever)

The biggest problem you had that was stopping the loop was `$(".white").html("START HERE!");` If you want to be interchangable with the Try Again then you have to make sure youre changing the same element (the span). What you did was overwrite the span html and then when you try to change it in the mouse over function theres nothing to change.

Check out the code and if you have any questions ask.

```
$(".wall").hover(function () {
    $(this).css("background", '#000');
    //clear the sad face and stop the animation and reset text
    $('#highlight_lose').fadeOut(1000);
    $(".white span").removeAttr('style');
    $(".white span").clearQueue().stop().finish();
    $(".white span").html("START HERE!");
})

$(".way").bind('mouseenter', function () {
    $('#highlight_lose').fadeIn(1000);
    $('.wall').css("background", '#fff');
    $(".white span").html("Try again");

    function move() {
        //Animate this way so when its done going left it starts going right. Then when
        //its done going right clear the style so it goes back to the starting positon
        //and call it again so it loops until you hit the path.
        $(".white span").animate({
            "margin-left": "-=10px"
        }, 300, function () {
            $(".white span").animate({
                "margin-left": "+=10px"
            }, 300, function () {
                $(".white span").removeAttr('style');
                move();

            });
        });
    }
    //Clear everything before you call move again so it doesnt over animate.
    $(".white span").removeAttr('style');
    $(".white span").clearQueue().stop().finish();
    move();
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uqcLn/55/

Comment: haha thanks so much for your will to help and time!! for me it do the trick the only problem for me now is that it's steel allowing to start the maze from square "1" as i example u here: http://jsfiddle.net/uqcLn/56/

Comment: Do you mean its allowing you to start the maze from anywhere?? Do you want it to only be able to start from square 1?? EDIT: just kidding I didnt see the 1 you put in there. I assume you only want to be able to start from the very first square?

Comment: yes... i mean it's allowing u to start the maze from almost anywhere, i don't want to let that happened. only when the mouse leave completly the main div i want the maze will refresh i think u got me...

Comment: Okay check this out... http://jsfiddle.net/uqcLn/58/ I added gave the start box an id and added an event on it. The only problem is that I once you mess up you can start from the beginning again but the black only fills in once you leave the frist box. Its weird but play around with it. Read my comments in the code to see what I was doing.

Comment: The problem is to make it only start at the front you have to unbind the call that makes the squares turn black but then make it rebind on the start key. Its quite annoying because if you dont unbind it after you mess up once you can start anywhere on the maze. Thus you have to try and rebind it and that was the only solution I could find quickly

Comment: deeply appreciate your help this is beyond what i expected thanks very much for your time and help, really.

Comment: No problem... Keeps me busy at work when I have nothing to do :D